# How to use default property value to define another property in Nuxt config?

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js, nuxt.js

There is `dev` property in Nuxt configuration, and according to documentation it is overwritten by the nuxt commands:

- `dev` is forced to `true` with `nuxt`
- `dev` is forced to `false` with `nuxt build`

How do I access this forced value in Nuxt config when I do not define it manually?
I have another property that I want to make dependent on `dev` value.

I know how to do it using env vars:

```js
anotherProp: process.env.dev === true
```

But behavior should not change depending on env var from `.env` and should instead use `dev` value forced by Nuxt.

Comment: Have you checked [this](https://v2.nuxt.com/fr/docs/internals-glossary/context/#isdev) ?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve a problem.

As I understand it's not the `dev` property itself that is being forced by Nuxt, but rather `NODE_ENV` env var, and then

```js
dev: process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production'
```

So I can define my property using `NODE_ENV` directly (since I already know how to work with it):

```js
anotherProp: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production'
```